# Python's binary representation of negative numbers

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I have been trying to understand which representation is used by python for storing negative integers ([1s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), [2s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) or [signed bit representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign%E2%80%93magnitude)). For that, I tried out these functions

```
>>> bin(-10)
'-0b1010'
>>> bin(10)
'0b1010'
>>> format(10,'b')
'1010'
>>> format(-10,'b')
'-1010'
>>> format(-10,'16b')
'           -1010'
>>> format(-10,'32b')
'                           -1010'
>>> format(-10,'64b')
'                                                           -1010'
```

However, `-1010` is not any of the above 3 representations (how is it storing the - symbol ?). The representation here I am getting is just `-` in front of the standard binary representation of the positive counterpart. So, how can I know the actual representation?

Comment: It's implementation-dependent - the "-" isn't being stored _anywhere_, it's just how Python displays values that are negative.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If "-" isn't stored anywhere then how does Python "remember" that the value is negative?

Comment: Again, that's implementation-dependent. E.g. there are details for CPython in https://stackoverflow.com/q/23016610/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, I checked you linked answer and understood.  How can I close this question ?